# ScriptableObject not working after build in Unity?

Tags: unity

I have a GameObject with a ScriptableObject on it, `stats`. It works fine in editor but when I try to build I get a message,

`A script behaviour (script unknown or not yet loaded) has a different serialization layout when loading.`

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out, I had changed the ScriptableObject (added a new property) after I'd already created the `.asset` file.

Going to the `.asset` file and re-setting the Script component fixed this. Making a new one would also work.